# Is there a good way to change the element's height according to the window size?

Tags: sass, screen-resolution

I am using height with 'vh' units but it's not as good as I want.
I have a drop down that have in it a scroll, it's size is: 'height:32vh', In the smallest resolution I need to support it's look ok (there is a good scroll and the dropdown is not catted). But in large screen I want the dropdown to be higher then the value of 32vh.
Before I used 'vh' units, I used max-height: 320px, but the dropdown in small resolution was catted and if I put less then 320px in big screen the dropdown is too short.
Is there a solution to this problem?

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="arrow-up"></div>

<div class="checkbox group">
    <label class="ng-binding">
    ...
    </label>
</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link select-btn ng-binding" ng-disabled="isSelectAllDisabled()" ng-click="selectAll()" disabled="disabled">Select All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link select-btn ng-binding" ng-click="selectNone()">Select None</button>
</div>
<div class="columns-list scroll">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
        ...
</div>
```

The style:

```
.parent {
    height: 34vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.columns-list.scroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: did you try using media queries?

Comment: No I didn't try it. Thanks, I will try using it. Maybe you know which rule is suitable in this case?